# Re Use of DefaultTableModel

Tags: java, swing, jtable, defaulttablemodel

```
    DefaultTableModel dtm = new DefaultTableModel(new Object[]{"SR#", "Date", "Name", "Description", "Quantity", "Weight", "Rate", "Total",  "Balance","Paid","Net Pay"},0);
            table = new JTable();
            table.setModel(dtm); 
            JScrollPane scroller=new JScrollPane(table);

            table.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255,226,226));
            scroller.setBounds(0,0,1335,380);
            p2.add(scroller);
                while(rs.next()){
        dtm.addRow(new Object[]{rs.getString(1),rs.getString(2),rs.getString(3),rs.getString(4),rs.getString(5),rs.getString(6),rs.getString(7),rs.getString(8),rs.getString(9),rs.getString(10),rs.getString(11)});
```

How can I re use this code several times in my program without creating a new object every time when an event is occurred.

Comment: A comment on your code style, please use `{}` for all your blocks. It looks weird when you start all of that code with an if statement!

Comment: Apologies for the style, it was too much indented, however, if you can help me with the issue it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got the solution to my Problem. I just need to call 2 methods whenever I press a button before running the SQL Query. Those 2 methods are

**panel.removeAll();** and

**panel.validate();**

This erase everything on your previous panel from your screen and displays only the result which you desire to see.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you have declared the `JTable` globally and initializing every time when some action event is triggered.

As like `JTable`, you can declare your `DefaultTableModel` globally and initialize both `JTable` and `TableModel`.

If you don't want to maintain the old records in `JTable`, you can clear the `JTable` every time when some action event is trigerred.

Comment: Thank you so much brother, for understanding my question, I really appreciate, However, I have done that as well, And I am not getting the proper out put, Even if I write the code to clear the tables even though  table is not getting cleared. If you don't mind reading my program from start till end or compile and execute on your system I can show you my entire code, however, its large enough. I know somewhere I am going wrong but I am unable to track it. Please help me brother.

Comment: Run your program in debug mode and see what is actually going wrong. If you couldn't find it, please share your code to logumohan@gmail.com, I can check.

Comment: This is my code brother, I have updated it, Please have a look. You can run this code directly on your system, however, you need to set DSN first and u need to have an access database file with 11 columns in it and insert the records until you get the scroller. This is the main issue. Scroller is getting overlapped. Please help me brother.

Comment: One of my weak point is this, I have written this code on notepad each and every line is been typed by me. I have not used any CMS or other tool for it.

Comment: I have sent you an email, You need to do the following before you run the code to implement on your machine:

1. Set the system DSN with name MominDB.mdb (its an microsoft access file).

2. Fill up the table named as CTS ( table name is CTS) from where all the data is been fetched.

3. Fill up the table until you get the scroller down. (This is the main issue) Scroller is getting overlaped.